# How to save video in VLC with filters applied

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

I want to *SAVE* (not just play) a video in VLC with a rotation filter applied, so that I don't have to select the filter every time I open the file.

The Media->Convert Options only show available codecs and subtitles, but I can't see any option to apply the filter.

Comment: it's doable from CLI but I've never done it in the gui

Answer (score 2):

http://kevinstechsupport.blogspot.fr/2012/12/videolan-vlc-player-saving-transformed.html?m=1

This is the only option that works for those of us who no nothing about programming and sfuff.