# How to Save Video with Image Processing Filter Applied in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

I added a brightness/contrast filter to VLC and would like to save my video with the filter applied. Many answers like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/212393/how-to-save-video-in-vlc-with-filters-applied) are outdated. What's the current way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. When you save the video, you have to enable "Image Properties Filter" in the conversion profile. I included a full tutorial below

### Tutorial

**1**. Open the "Save" dialog for your video. You can also do this through `Media`>`Convert / Save`

[image: Opening the "Convert/Save" dialog]

**2**. Choose a conversion profile, and go into its settings. (I would actually recommend creating a new profile specifically for enabling filters, so you don't have to change the profile back after you're done. However, in that case you would have to configure the Encapsulation, Video codec, and Audio codec, which you could manually copy from an existing profile)

[image: Opening the Profile Editor]

**3**. Under the `Video Codec` tab, make sure "Video" is checked and "Keep original video track" is unchecked. Then go to the `Filters` sub-tab and check "Image properties filter"

[image: Profile Editor]

**4**. Now just click "Save" to save the profile, give a destination file path, and click "Start"!

[image: convert it!]

**5**. In step 2, if you modified an existing profile instead of creating a new one, don't forget to go back and uncheck "Image properties filter", otherwise every time you use that profile your videos will come out filtered!